Ending Trend Lines After Breakout
The code below automatically draws trend lines and generates signals when there is a breakout. After the breakout, it checks the next candle for confirmation, and if confirmation occurs, it ends the trend line and returns true for hasCrossed. What I want to do, however, is to end the trend line at the candle where the breakout occurs, even if there is no confirmation afterward. Of course, if there is confirmation after the breakout, I still want to generate a signal. If nextbarconfirmed doesn't work, I don't want to generate a signal.
//@version=5
strategy("TREND BACKTEST", overlay=true, pyramiding=4, initial_capital=100,default_qty_type = strategy.cash, calc_on_order_fills=false,default_qty_value = 300, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.02,calc_on_every_tick=true)

import HoanGhetti/SimpleTrendlines/4 as tl

input_len       = input.int(defval = 20, title = 'Pivot Length', minval = 1)
input_pivotType = input.string(defval = 'Normal', title = 'Pivot Type', options = ['Normal', 'Fast'], tooltip = 'Normal: Uses Pine\'s built-in pivot system.\n\nFast: Uses a custom pivot system that tracks every reversal.')
input_repaint   = input.bool(defval = true, title = 'Repainting', tooltip = 'If disabled, it will wait for bar confirmation to avoid printing false alerts.')
input_targets   = input.bool(defval = false, title = 'Target Levels')
input_bearC     = input.color(defval = color.red, title = 'Bear Breakout', group = 'Styling')
input_bullC     = input.color(defval = color.green, title = 'Bull Breakout', group = 'Styling')
input_extend    = input.string(defval = extend.none, title = 'Extend', options = [extend.none, extend.right, extend.left, extend.both], group = 'Styling')
input_style     = input.string(defval = line.style_dotted, title = 'Trendline Style', options = [line.style_dotted, line.style_dashed, line.style_solid], group = 'Styling')
input_tstyle    = input.string(defval = line.style_dashed, title = 'Target Style', options = [line.style_dotted, line.style_dashed, line.style_solid], group = 'Styling')
input_override  = input.bool(defval = false, title = 'Override Source', group = 'Override', tooltip = 'Overriding the source will allow the script to create trendlines on any specified source.')
input_useSrc    = input.bool(defval = true, title = 'Use Source for Cross Detection', group = 'Override', tooltip = 'Instead of checking if the close value crossed trendline, check for the specified source.')
input_source    = input.source(defval = low, title = 'Source', group = 'Override')

pl = fixnan(ta.pivotlow(input_override ? input_source : low, input_pivotType == 'Normal' ? input_len : 1, input_len))
ph = fixnan(ta.pivothigh(input_override ? input_source : high, input_pivotType == 'Normal' ? input_len : 1, input_len))

pivot(float pType) =>
    pivot = pType == pl ? pl : ph
    xAxis = ta.valuewhen(ta.change(pivot), bar_index, 0) - ta.valuewhen(ta.change(pivot), bar_index, 1)
    prevPivot = ta.valuewhen(ta.change(pivot), pivot, 1)
    pivotCond = ta.change(pivot) and (pType == pl ? pivot > prevPivot : pivot < prevPivot)
    pData = tl.new(x_axis = xAxis, offset = input_len, strictMode = true, strictType = pType == pl ? 0 : 1)
    pData.drawLine(pivotCond, prevPivot, pivot, input_override ? input_source : na)
    pData

breakout(tl.Trendline this, float pType) =>
    var bool hasCrossed = false
    var bool nextBarConfirmed = false

    if ta.change(this.lines.startline.get_y1())
        hasCrossed := false

    this.drawTrendline(not hasCrossed)
    confirmation = not hasCrossed and (input_repaint ? not hasCrossed : barstate.isconfirmed)

    if (pType == pl ? (input_override and input_useSrc ? input_source : close) < this.lines.trendline.get_y2() : (input_override and input_useSrc ? input_source : close) > this.lines.trendline.get_y2()) and confirmation
        nextBarConfirmed := (pType == pl ? (input_override and input_useSrc ? input_source[1] : close[1]) < this.lines.trendline.get_y2() : (input_override and input_useSrc ? input_source[1] : close[1]) > this.lines.trendline.get_y2()) and confirmation
        if nextBarConfirmed
            hasCrossed := true
            this.lines.startline.set_xy2(this.lines.trendline.get_x2(), this.lines.trendline.get_y2())
            this.lines.trendline.set_xy2(na, na)
            this.lines.startline.copy()

    hasCrossed


plData = pivot(pl)
phData = pivot(ph)


style(tl.Trendline this, color col) =>
    this.lines.startline.set_color(col), this.lines.trendline.set_color(col)
    this.lines.startline.set_width(2), this.lines.trendline.set_width(2)
    this.lines.trendline.set_style(input_style), this.lines.trendline.set_extend(input_extend)
style(plData, input_bearC), style(phData, input_bullC)

cu = breakout(plData, pl)
co = breakout(phData, ph)
plotshape(ta.change(cu) and cu ? plData.lines.startline.get_y2() : na, title = 'Bearish Breakout', style = shape.labeldown, color = input_bearC, textcolor = color.white, location = location.absolute, text = 'Br')
plotshape(ta.change(co) and co ? phData.lines.startline.get_y2() : na, title = 'Bullish Breakout', style = shape.labelup, color = input_bullC, textcolor = color.white, location = location.absolute, text = 'Br')
alertcondition(ta.change(cu) and cu, 'Bearish Breakout')
alertcondition(ta.change(co) and co, 'Bullish Breakout')

// Target Levels [v4 Update]
phData_target = tl.new(phData.values.changeInX)
plData_target = tl.new(plData.values.changeInX)
phData_target.drawLine(ta.change(phData.values.y1) and input_targets, phData.values.y2, phData.values.y2)
plData_target.drawLine(ta.change(plData.values.y1) and input_targets, plData.values.y2, plData.values.y2)

target_style(tl.Trendline this, color col) =>
    this.lines.startline.set_style(input_tstyle)
    this.lines.trendline.set_style(input_tstyle)
    this.lines.startline.set_color(col)
    this.lines.trendline.set_color(col)
target_style(plData_target, input_bearC)
target_style(phData_target, input_bullC)
breakout(phData_target, ph)
breakout(plData_target, pl)

